# SQL Select Like Column Name from table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

The goal is to create a Oracle Function that is capable of query column name off a token provided by the user as to create a function with such capabilities

```
select cols_like('%e%') from table
```

This is the point I am currently at

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function COLS_LIKE 
(v_search in VARCHAR2, v_table in VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR
IS
    TYPE r_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
    c_emp         r_cursor;
    crs_cols      VARCHAR(255);
    column_list   VARCHAR(1000);
BEGIN    
    OPEN c_emp FOR 
        'select COLUMN_NAME from cols 
         where TABLE_NAME = ''' || v_table || ''' 
         and column_name like ''' || v_search || ''''; 
LOOP
    FETCH c_emp INTO crs_cols;

    EXIT WHEN c_emp%NOTFOUND;

    if column_list IS NULL THEN 
        column_list := crs_cols;
    else 
        column_list := column_list || ', ' || crs_cols;
    end if;
END LOOP; 

RETURN column_list;

END;
```

Where you call the function such as this

```
Declare
    tests VARCHAR(100);
    sql_stmt VARCHAR2(200);
begin
    tests := COLS_LIKE('%E%', 'table');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tests);
-- OR
    sql_stmt := 'select ' || COLS_LIKE('%E%', 'table') || ' from table';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sql_stmt);
end;
```

The end goal would be something such as this

```
select COLS_LIKE('%E%', 'table') from table;
```

**What modifications can I make to my function or how I am calling to so that this function can be applied correctly.**

Answer (score 2):

*Why* you'd want to do such a thing I've no idea but you could return an open cursor to PL/SQL fairly easily:

```
create or replace function cols_like (
     PTable in varchar2
   , PColumn in varchar2
     ) return sys_refcursor

   l_cols varchar2(32767);
   c_curs sys_refcursor;

begin

   select listagg(column_name, ', ') within group (order by column_id)
     into l_cols
     from user_tab_cols
    where table_name = upper(Ptable)
      and column_name like '%' || upper(PColumn) || '%'
          ;

   open c_curs for '
     select ' || l_cols || '
       from ' || Ptable;

   return c_curs;

end;
/
```

Returning this to a standard SQL statement will be *a lot* more difficult, this is because in selecting this function you're only selecting *one* column's worth of data. You want to be able to select *N* columns, which means you need to start returning nested tables that have been dynamically created.

I'm sure it's possible; but, before you get anywhere close to starting to attempt to do this think about *why* you're doing it. Ask a question where you don't state your end goal but where you state what your actual problem is. Chances are there's a lot simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having same problem and found this, and it is working for me. I was just making comparison of mobile numbers from two tables and in one of the tables some numbers have 0 in start and some don't. Finally got solution and just added % in start:

```
a.number was having numbers, in some of them starting 0 was missing. and b.number was accurate.

b.number like CONCAT('%',a.number)
```